# Popper not sticking to ref element on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, popper.js, popperjs

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-euler-rep54

Click on any "click me to set ref". The popper correctly positions itself. Now start scrolling, and you'll see the popper doesn't stick to the ref.

If you move `.popper` to be a direct child of `.scroll-body`, it works.

```html
<div id="app">
    <div class="scroll-body">
      <div v-for="n in 40">
          <span @click="setRef" class="ref">
            click me to set ref
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ref="popper" class="popper">popper</div>
</div>
```

What popper option do I need to set to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid changing the reference after the instance has been created like `state.elements.reference = newReference` and instead create a fresh popper instance entirely. The reason is the `scrollParents` detection is done when the instance is created (or updated).

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-night-5vjfm

You can change the reference dynamically if you call `.setOptions({})` after setting it though, but I would recommend the above instead.

Comment: Cool, I copied code from this github comment. It's probably not recommended, but it works. https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core/issues/538#issuecomment-596601887. I like your solution better, thanks. EDIT: haha.. just realized you were the one who suggested the original solution https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core/issues/538#issuecomment-362141790

Answer (score 1):

If you put overflow-y: scroll; on #app, it will work the way you want. Overflow-y needs to be set on the parent for it to affect the child.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this issue, in my case, I forget to set container `overflow: auto`.